# Variável me retornando undefined que é atribuída dentro de subscribe

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

No código abaixo, a variável **data** esta me retornando **undefined**, agora se eu colocar **console.log(this.data);** dentro de **subscribe** me retorna com o valor correto.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-aniversario',
  templateUrl: './aniversario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./aniversario.component.css']
})
export class AniversarioComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any;
  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.http.get('assets/aniversarios.json').subscribe(res => {
     this.data = res.json();
   });
   console.log(this.data);
  }
}
```

Como eu posso pegar o valor de **res** que está no **subscribe** ?

Comment: talvez esse problema está relacionado com o objeto que o this está referenciando em cada função e não com os callbacks, como sugere a duplicada. caso seja isso: antes do ngOnInit() coloca var self = this; e trabalha dentro do subscribe com self ao inves do this.

Comment: Acho que você esta se confundido. O método `subscribe` faz parte da classe `Observable` que trabalham com chamadas assíncronas. Acredito que você estava obtendo `undefined` pois estava chamando o `console.log` antes do valor ser retornado pelo `subscribe`. O que posso recomendar é que leia [este](https://medium.com/senaiinformatica/entendendo-rxjs-observable-com-angular-6f607a9a6a00) material e tente compreender como funcionam as chamadas assíncronas com os `Observables`.

Comment: Exatamente isto que o @Carlinhos falou, `subscribe` trabalha com chamadas assíncronas, neste caso o console está logando antes mesmo de a resposta ser devolvida e jogada para a variável `data`. Não é porque está `undefined` no momento do `console.log` que os dados não estão ali, mas sim que naquele momento não estavam disponíveis. Se você implementar uma interface verá que data recebe os valores posteriormente ao carregamento.